# Stripe browser compatible

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, stripe-payments, mobile-safari

Doing cross-browser support using a [Iphone 5s emulator](https://live.browserstack.com/) running safari 10 and under I noticed some code is not supported.

https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/client/web/script.js

When going through the error logs, I found that 'fetch' is not supported in that browser so I installed a polyfill

and that required 'promise' so I installed another polyfill

and now I'm getting an error with this code:

```
.then(function({ stripe, card, clientSecret }) {
```

The curly brackets aren't supported, I am not sure where to go with this, if there is a straight forward fix or should I try to recode this .js file without using polyfills.

Comment: You could use babel.js to compile your script into a version that is es2015 compatible

Comment: @empiric Thanks I found my fix on babel.js. Changed it to .then(function (_ref) {
    var stripe = _ref.stripe,
        card = _ref.card,
        clientSecret = _ref.clientSecret;